# HP DV6500T downgrade bios?

Tags: downgrade

My fan is really loud, and I can't use speedfan to control it because it can't detect the sensors. I want to downgrade my bios since F.40 changes fans stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a version, [download from HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/previousVersions?softwareitem=ob-67682-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=2093&product=3369405).